# Okta - passing okta profile parameters to a URL from the signin widget

Tags: parameter-passing, portal, user-profile, okta

I am using the Okta signin widget to validate users for a program I wrote and would like to pass in some of the Okta profile data to my application thru a URL.  When I look at the object that Okta creates (res), it only seems to expose a few of the profile attributes such as firstName, lastName, locale, timeZone and login.  The javascripts alerts show as undefined for all other user profile attributes.  Is there any way to access the additional profile attributes from an okta profile within this script or is there another way that this can be done thru the Okta portal itself.  I included the signin script from my code below:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var baseUrl = 'https://<my company>.okta.com';
            var logo = 'https://ok2static.oktacdn.com/bc/image/fileStoreRecord?id=<myid>;
            var oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn({
                baseUrl: baseUrl, logo: logo,
                labels: {
                          'primaryauth.title': 'Login',
                          'primaryauth.username.tooltip': '(email address)'
                        }
            });

            oktaSignIn.renderEl(
              {el: '#okta-login-container'},
              function (res) {
                  alert(res.user.profile.login);
                  alert(res.user.profile.firstName);
                  alert(res.user.profile.lastName);
                  alert(res.user.profile.locale);
                  alert(res.user.profile.timeZone);
                  alert(res.user.profile.streetAddress);
                  alert(res.user.profile.countryCode);
                  alert(res.user.profile.city);
                  alert(res.user.profile.nickName);
                  alert(res.user.profile.displayName);
                  alert(res.user.profile.email);
                  alert(res.user.profile.secondEmail);
                  alert(res.user.profile.profileUrl);
                  alert(res.user.profile.preferredLanguage);
                  alert(res.user.profile.userType);
                  alert(res.user.profile.organization);
                  alert(res.user.profile.title);
                  alert(res.user.profile.division);
                  alert(res.user.profile.department);
                  alert(res.user.profile.costCenter);
                  alert(res.user.profile.employeeNumber);
                  alert(res.user.profile.mobilePhone);
                  alert(res.user.profile.primaryPhone);
                  alert(res.user.profile.city);
                  alert(res.user.profile.state);
                  alert(res.user.profile.zipCode);


                  if (res.status === 'SUCCESS') { res.session.setCookieAndRedirect('http://www.myprogram.aspx?<this is where I would like to pass in Okta profile parameters like streetAddress or City>); }
              }
            );
        </script>
```

Is there some way to change to change this statement to go to the Okta portal and pass in parameters from there within okta itself (create an app in okta that I can pass user profile parameters to) ?

```
                  if (res.status === 'SUCCESS') { res.session.setCookieAndRedirect('https://<mycompany>.okta.com); }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to SSO enable your application (SAML or WS-Fed) and then configure Okta to use a custom login page for the app. Okta redirects with a "fromURI" parameter if the custom login page is enabled for the application.

```
res.session.setCookieAndRedirect(fromURI QueryStringParameter);
```

Okta would then send all the info you needed via SSO which is configured per app in Okta.

If you stick with your current API only approach you could use the [Get User API](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#get-user). You can substitute "me" for the id to fetch the current user linked to API token or session cookie.